# Can region be defined outside of the theme's .info file?

Tags: theming, .info

Basically I'm trying to reverse-engineer a theme that was developed by another guy. The problem is that I'm not yet quite firm on Drupal ground.

So I'm looking onto a management page for blocks and see a specific region, which is not defined in theme's .info file...

Can regions be defined elsewhere? Or inherited from somewhere else (another theme maybe)?

**UPDATE**:
Since to inherit something this should be a sub-theme, which should be denoted by:

> base theme = themeName

line in *themeName.info* file. But there is no such line in this theme... :( This undefined region should be coming from somewhere else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it turned out that it was the region defined in .info file after all. It's just that Drupal I was working with was using different language pack and simply silently translated region names were it could. That's what confused me - one region got translated and the rest stayed intact.

Might be useful for someone hitting the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 7 has 5 [default regions](https://drupal.org/node/171224):

- regions[sidebar_first] = Left sidebar
- regions[sidebar_second] = Right
  sidebar
- regions[content] = Content
- regions[header] = Header
- regions[footer] = Footer
- regions[highlighted] = Highlighted
- regions[help] = Help

Regions aren't inherited by parent themes: https://drupal.org/node/225125.

If I'm not mistaken you used to be able to define regions in [theme_region()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--theme.php/function/theme_region/7), but I believe that's no longer being used.

Comment: Now that's weird - for theme to become a sub-theme there should be a: base theme = themeName line in themeName.info file right? But I do not see any...

But the link you've provided says: "Sub-themes do not inherit custom regions from a parent theme. If you are using custom regions, you should copy the region declarations from the parent theme's .info file. Be sure your sub-theme's page.tpl.php file matches the sub-theme's region settings."

Comment: Parsed the whole Drupal 6 tree for a theme_region string, but found nothing...